# How to get from form input absolute value?

Tags: php

I know it is abs() but why this one does not work ? in php or if its wrong how to make it right:

```
<?php 
    echo "Number";
    echo "\x20"; 
    echo $_GET["luku"];
    echo "\x20"; 
    echo "absolute value is";
    echo "\x20"; 
    echo $_GET[abs("luku")]; 
?>
```

first `$_GET` is working but second one not.
Im just increasing my knowledge on php

Comment: The abs should go around the entire get, not within the key for get ‘abs($_GET[“luku”])’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something is wrong in your code at this line. `echo $_GET[abs("luku")]`;

use this

```
echo abs($_GET["luku"]);
```

`abs` is a function call `$_GET` request inside the function. In short, place `$_GET["luku"]` inside `()` of `abs`

Comment: @JustBaron thank you for edit, no issue with that, in fact happy for easy knowledge shating :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to echo `$_GET[0]:`

```
<?php
var_dump(abs("luku"));
```

Output:

```
int(0)
```

To fix, nest appropriately:

```
echo abs($_GET['luku']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `abs` function for getting argument. But the `abs` function use for the geting absolute value of the integer or float.

In your case there is a string, so the function return 0 and the `global` `$_GET` has no value at 0 index.

That's why you are not getting value.